# Ember, how to copy value/label of selected item of Ember.Select to next TextField?

Tags: ember.js, html-select

I have a simple construction `Ember.Select` holding some predefined strings and `Ember.TextField` next to it:

```
{{view Ember.Select
    prompt="Choose..."
    contentBinding="predefinedLabels"
    optionValuePath="content.value"
    optionLabelPath="content.label"
}}
{{view Ember.TextField  valueBinding='view.newLabel' action='saveNewLabel'}}
```

I need to on select change get it's current value (if not prompt) and set it to the `TextField` and then reset the select to the prompt state - sounds trivial, but I have no idea how to do that :( I tried by using `selectionBinding` but problem is that these sets Select+ TextField are created dynamically. with common jQuery I would do it with common `change` listener added to the all `select` tags with some specified class, what is equivalent of the similar behavior in the Ember? (or what is proper way to do what I need?

Comment: maybe I can still save your day... have a look at my answer :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can still do just that with jQuery. Just put the relevant code (attaching `change` listeners) into the `didInsertElement`  method of your current view.

See [this working jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/chopper/CS3em/).

```
App.ApplicationView = Ember.View.extend({
    didInsertElement: function() {
        var self = this;
        this.$('select').change(function() {
            self.$('input').val(self.$('option:selected').text());
            self.$("option:selected").removeAttr("selected");
        });
    }
});
```

Comment: Will be an effort for you to place some sample (or link to sample)? I resolved many mysterious puzzles with Ember, but this one just ruined my day :/ Thanks in advance!

Comment: Thx very much, your fiddle does what I need, now I just need to check why my app doesn't.

Comment: No problem. If you get stuck, just post a jsFiddle and we can try to fix it :)

Answer (score 1):

Do I understand you correctly?

Is this the behaviour you are looking for: http://jsbin.com/aqaYEgo/3/edit

Basically:

```
App.ApplicationController = Ember.ObjectController.extend({
  selectedLabel: null,
  actions: {
    saveNewLabel: function() {
      console.log('Saving label: ' + this.get('selectedLabel.value'));
    }
  }
});

{{view Ember.Select
  prompt="Choose..."
  contentBinding="model"
  optionValuePath="content.value"
  optionLabelPath="content.label"
  selectionBinding="selectedLabel"
}}
{{view Ember.TextField  valueBinding="controller.selectedLabel.value" action='saveNewLabel'}}
```

Hope it helps.

Comment: Thanks for sample! I know this possibility but it unfortunately doesn't resolve two most important assumptions: it blanks the `TextField` when prompt - `Choose...` selected and it doesn't resets the Select to the prompt state after pasting the value into textfield.